# How can I remove HTML markup from strings in state data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

1. I fetch data from an API using 'axios'.
2. I save the data recieved in my State.
3. I output the information given from the state in a table.

The issue is that the Strings I recieve from the fetched data include a lot of HTML tags such as `< p >`, `< h1 >` & `< br >`
I would like to remove these if possible.

Note that I do not use JQuery

```
state = {
  companyName: "Loading",
      loading: true,
         data: [] //THIS IS WHERE I STORE ALL THE DATA THAT I FETCH
}
```

```
data(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <Table celled>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Index</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Författning</Table.HeaderCell>

          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        {props.map((lawList, index) => (
                    <Table.Body>
                      <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>{index + 1}</Table.Cell>
/* The line below displays the data, but the data includes alot of html tags that i wish to have removed */
                        <Table.Cell>{lawList.lawDTO.name}</Table.Cell>
                      </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Body>
            ))}
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
                <h3> {this.data(this.state.data)} </h3>

        </div>   
     )}
   }
```

Comment: JQuery is not used

Comment: Put it in your question, please.

Comment: Can you get the API to return the same data without the HTML tags?

Comment: @Shilly
No unfortunatley. the data come with the HTML tags

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, as soon aj you have read your data:

```js
let data = "<p>first <h1> second <br> third </p>";
data = data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```js
const test = '<br>asdasd</br><p>test</p>'.replace(/<.{1,2}>|<.{2,3}>/g, '');
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you want to [render the html](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)?

```
render() {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }}></div>
  )
}
```